# Application icon is missing in the taskbar during program start, if another application is active

Tags: wpf, icons, taskbar, splash-screen

I've written a WPF application which has a custom (not the standard) icon. A Splashscreen is implemented too.

The icon is correctly displayed if I start the application and wait until it is loaded.

But, if I start my application and switch to another application (e.g. Outlook) before the my splash screen is shown, the icon is not displayed in the windows task bar.

The icon appears directly if I switch via alt+tab to my application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a program written in another language (PowerBuilder, and not the .Net bases one) that behaves exactly the same. Must be a Windows problem if it affects more than just WPF. So there must be a way to work-around this.

Maybe the framework ask for "my" taskbar item in the wrong way if it isn't active.

The taskbar icon reappears when setting focus back to the application.

A crude solution is to do this (Pseudo code):

```
application.Hide();
application.Show()
```

Another solution (Pseudo code):

```
application.SetRedraw(False);
application.Show();
application.SetRedraw(True);
```

But this creates a nasty blinking. A solution that just "reactivates" or "redraws" toolbar would be better!

The cause of the problem (in my non WPF case) is that the program shows a UI before the constructor of the main window is complete. I.e. a force redraw/show of the window before all initialization code is done. This probably causes Windows to think the window isn't an application but rather a "dialog" of the splash screen and not assigning a taskbar item. When I managed to remove the code that prematurely showed the main GUI the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with a Winforms app. The solution I found may help your WPF app too.

Simply make sure the window's title isn't changed, until the last possible moment. In Winforms, I moved the `Text = "blahblah"` line out of the Form_load event, and into the Form1_Shown event, and now that hidden taskbar icon problem has vanished.

Answer (score -1):

I see a similar problem on some OS but not all. When I switch program, the icon I have in my taskbar is changed to the default application onw (the "empty window"). It seems to be a problem with WPF itself, not anything with your program per say.